# Does converting json to dict with eval a good choice?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, eval

I am getting a json object from a remote server, and converting it to a python string like this:

```
a = eval(response)
```

Is this stupid in any way, or do I have a better option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `eval` is not a good way to process JSON:

1. JSON isn't even valid Python, because of `true`, `false`, and `null`.
2. `eval` will execute arbitrary Python code, so you are at the mercy of malicious injection of code.

Use the `json` module available in the standard library instead:

```
import json
data = json.loads("[1, 2, 3]")
```

If you're using a version of Python older than 2.6, you'll need to download the module yourself. It's called `simplejson` and can be [downloaded from PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/).

Comment: (1) it's easy to take care of the literals, like so: `eval(json_str, {'false': False, 'true': True, 'null': None})`

Comment: (2) can you explain how arbitrary code can be executed by `eval`, provided that access to builtins is removed with `eval(str, {'__builtins__':{ }})` ?

Comment: @NasBanov: with eval as you have shown it, you *may* be safe.  But why go to that trouble when `json.loads` is right there, and is guaranteed safe?

Comment: @NasBanov: actually, you are not safe with your eval.  Try it with this value of str:  str = """[n for n in {}.__class__.__bases__[-1].__subclasses__() if n.__name__ == "Quitter"][0](0)()"""

Comment: ah, excellent work, Sir - i `+1` salute you! ... i wondered if taking away the globals can jail eval and you proved it's not

Answer (score 2):

Yes, very. Use a json decoder instead:

```
>>> from simplejson import loads
>>> loads(response)
```