# python eval vs ast.literal_eval vs JSON decode

Tags: python

I am converting 2 MB of data as a string into a dict.
The input is serialized in JSON.

Anyways I am currently using ast.literal_eval and I get the dictionary I want, but then when I tried just running eval it seems to run faster, and also returns the same result.

Is there any reason to use the ast module or the json module when eval works just fine?

Comment: eval is prone to security threats. Use only when you absolutely control what gets eval'ed

Comment: If you want to distribute the dictionary alongside with your code, you can laso simply put it in a Python module and import it.  That way, you make clear this is Python code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't really like this attitude on stackoverflow (and elsewhere) telling people without any context that what they are doing is insecure and they shouldn't do it. Maybe it's just a throwaway script to import some data, in that case why not choose the fastest or most convenient way?

In this case, however, `json.loads` is not only more secure, but also more than 4x faster (depending on your data).

```
In [1]: %timeit json.loads(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.6 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit eval(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 194 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit ast.literal_eval(data)
1000 loops, best of 3: 269 µs per loop
```

If you think about it makes sense json is a such more constrained language/format than python, so it must be faster to parse with an optimized parser.

Comment: SO is about more than answering the OP's question: it becomes a reference that other people read, too.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there's definitely a reason:  `eval()` is evil.  Your code might read untrusted data one day, an this would allow an attacker to run arbitrary code on your machine.

You shouldn't use `ast.literal_eval()` to decode JSON either.  It cannot decode every valid JSON string and is not meant to be used for this purpose.  Simply use `json.loads()`, it's reasonably fast.

Comment: What if they can only run it on their own machine? (eg: they download it and run it)

Comment: @Keikoku: So if it's not your machine, you don't care?

Comment: I guess they could spread it around and do dubious things with it and credit me for the work.

Comment: what about defining pyson, an amazing python/python interchange/storage format, whose only spec is : anything parseable without error by `ast.literal_eval()` :)

Answer (score 16):

No. Unless you hit one of two scenarios:

1. That's not JSON!

   Someone puts `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` in the file instead. You are boned.
2. It's JSON, but not the Python-like part!

   Someone puts `true`, `false`, `null`, or a Unicode escape somewhere in it. Happy birthday.

Comment: How about 
`eval(json_str, {'false': False, 'true': True, 'null': None, '__builtins__': {}})`? ;-)

Comment: @NasBanov: see http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, yeah - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282905/does-converting-json-to-dict-with-eval-a-good-choice/7282959#comment14167166_7282959 - seems related by time too

Comment: @NasBanov: and now try `json_str = '"\\u2603"'`. The *expected* output is `u'\u2603'`. What you'll get instead is `'\\u2603'`. You cannot map your way out of that one either.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer exactly, but it should be noted that `eval` and `literal_eval` are not the same thing. The `ast.literal_eval` won't run arbitrary code.

That said, I agree with using JSON; I just wanted to point out that `eval` != `literal_eval`