# Get lists by reading file in Python

Tags: python, list, file, get

There is a matter that I can't resolve in Python.

I'm trying to get lists by reading file (like .xml or .txt).

I've put my lists in a big list in my file like it :

```
[[48,49,39,7,13,1,11],[46,27,19,15,24,8,4],[35,5,41,10,31,5,9],[12,9,22,2,36,9,2],[50,47,25,6,42,3,1]]
```

Now I'm looking for code to get this big list like a list, not like a string. In deed, I've already try some parts of code with open(), write() and read() functions. But Python returned me :

```
'[[48,49,39,7,13,1,11],[46,27,19,15,24,8,4],[35,5,41,10,31,5,9],[12,9,22,2,36,9,2],[50,47,25,6,42,3,1]]'
```

And it isn't a list, just a string. So I can't use list's functions to modify it.

Thanks for those who will answer to my problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well, a simple way is to parse it as a json string:

```
>>> import json
>>> l_str = '[[48,49,39,7,13,1,11],[46,27,19,15,24,8,4],[35,5,41,10,31,5,9],[12,9,22,2,36,9,2],[50,47,25,6,42,3,1]]'
>>> l = json.loads(l_str)
>>> print l
[[48, 49, 39, 7, 13, 1, 11], [46, 27, 19, 15, 24, 8, 4], [35, 5, 41, 10, 31, 5, 9], [12, 9, 22, 2, 36, 9, 2], [50, 47, 25, 6, 42, 3, 1]]
```

if you want to load a file that **only** contains that string, you can simply do it using the following:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('myfile') as f:
>>>     l = json.load(f)
>>>     print l
[[48, 49, 39, 7, 13, 1, 11], [46, 27, 19, 15, 24, 8, 4], [35, 5, 41, 10, 31, 5, 9], [12, 9, 22, 2, 36, 9, 2], [50, 47, 25, 6, 42, 3, 1]]
```

But if what you want is to serialize python *objects*, then you should instead use [`pickle`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) that's more powerful at that task…

Of course, there are other ways that others may give you to parse your string through an `eval()`-like function, but I *strongly* advice you against that, as this is dangerous and leads to insecure code. *Edit*: after reading @kamikai answer, I'm discovering about [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which looks like a decent option as well, though `json.loads()` [is more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276991/1290438).

Comment: +1. Been enjoying cruising through your regex and Python answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your example is truly representative of your data (i.e., your text file contains only a list of lists of integers), you can parse it as JSON:

```
import json
data = read_the_contents_of_the_file()
decoded = json.loads(data)
```

Replace `data = read_the_contents_of_the_file()` with your existing code for reading the contents as string.

Answer (score 1):

As seen [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python) the inbuilt `ast` module is probably your best bet, assuming the text is still valid python.

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval("[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]") # Returns nested lists
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json to load and parse the file:

```
import json
with open(my_file_path, "rb") as f:
    my_list = json.load(my_file_path)
```