# Parsing Python list with PHP

Tags: php, python, json

Is there any way to parse Python list in PHP?

I have data coming from Python stored in MySQL, something like this:

```
[{u'hello: u'world'}]
```

And need to use it in PHP script. The data is a valid JSON, only difference are those leading `u'`

So I can replace all `u'` with `'` and then replace all `'` with `"` to get it into json. When I replace everything, if there is `'` in the actual value, it is replaced by `"` as well and breaks the json.

So.. I tried a lot of stuff, but none of them was able to parse proper json thus my question: Is there any way to parse Python generated list/json-like data in PHP? I don't mind using some third-party library or etc, just want to get the data parsed...

Comment: Ideally, you should fix that Python program so that it's exporting actual JSON, using `json.dumps()`, rather than simply printing the `repr()` of the Python data structure.

Comment: By `u"` you mean  `u''`, don't you?

Comment: @felipsmartins: If the string contains a single quote then its Python representation will use double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Comment: Reviewer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34479722/2153237

Comment: The proper way is to store correctly serialized data. So, when you write data to mysql add serialization step: json.dumps(your_list_of_dicts). In this case you don't need any workarounds to parse not formalized strings anywhere.

Comment: I understad all comments above, but sice the python code is out of my hand, is there any way to parse it in php?

Comment: @PM2Ring OP said there's `u"` but it is not true since it causes syntax error. `u"` is not equals `u''`, `u""`

Comment: @Tom Can you post the code having all use cases? SO I can to help.

Comment: Why is it out of your hands? No external API could possibly be returning data in this format, which means the Python script must be something you or a colleague has written. You or they should fix it.

Comment: @felipsmartins basically: `[[{u'foo:u'bar, u'hello:u'I don't know'}]]` if it handles that, it should solve my problem. Also, if I could fix json to replace `'` with `"` ONLY around parameters and values but not in values that would do it

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am getting the data from database that is fed from third-party system...

Comment: Don't you have access to Python so you could use it to parse the data and then transform it into something PHP understands?

Comment: @deceze I suppose I could use command line somehow, but I was hoping for more elegant solution

Comment: How about if your PHP code calls a Python script to convert the data into legal JSON?

Comment: Quite honestly, putting it through a small Python script *is* the most elegant way IMO. Otherwise you'd have to replicate the Python string literal parser in PHP, which I would not attempt unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @deceze Can you give an example of that?

Comment: I guess there's no point running a Python program over your database to fix all the broken JSON, since that 3rd party system's just going to pollute it with more broken stuff in the future.

Comment: You ***really*** ought to report this as a bug to the third party...!

Comment: @Tom `[[{u'foo:u'bar, u'hello:u'I don't know'}]]` is an invalid structure.

Comment: Right, gonna use command line for now, and push them to change that. Unfortunately I am not the only database they are polluting, only happen to be the only one that doesnt use python on my end.. Thanks everyone

Comment: If you really have strings in the database that look like `[[{u'foo:u'bar, u'hello:u'I don't know'}]]` then things are even worse than we thought. Hopefully, it's actually more like `[[{u'foo': u'bar', u'hello': u"I don't know"}]]`, which _is_ legal Python.

Comment: Is the data inside this broken JSON just plain ASCII, or does it contain fancy stuff like accented characters? By default, `json.dumps` produces UTF-8 encoded output, but there are ways of dealing with that if you want plain ASCII.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry my typo, the strings are legal python. The string can be virtually anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to python, you can convert it to json from the command line. 
Here's an example.

```
$ echo "{u'key': u'value'}" |\
  python -c "import sys, json, ast; print(json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(sys.stdin.read())))"

{"key": "value"}
```

Here's a better formatted version of the python oneliner:

```
import sys, json, ast
data = ast.literal_eval(sys.stdin.read())
print(json.dumps(data))
```

By using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of regular `eval` we can evaluate the python dictionary literal and not worry about potential code execution vulnerabilities.

Comment: `eval` can be [dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) to use on arbitrary data. It's _far_ better to use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for something like this.

Comment: I've changed the answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949533/python-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval-vs-json-decode, why not just use json.loads instead of ast.literal_eval  ?

Comment: @parkamark Because the input is a python literal, not json.