# How to extract number from text in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, integer

I have the string listed below

```
str = ['"Consumers_Of_Product": {"count": 13115}']
```

How can I extract the number 13115 as it will change, so that it will always equal var. In other words how do I extract this number from this string?

Most things I've done previously have not worked and I think that is due to the syntax. I'm running Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to extract that number, provided there are no other numbers in that string, you can use `regex`. I renamed `str` to be `s` for the reason mentioned in @TigerhawkT3 answer.

```
import re
s = ['"Consumers_Of_Product": {"count": 13115}']
num = re.findall('\d+', s[0])
print(num[0])
13115
```

Comment: My answer appears as ['13115'], How can I make that just a number

Comment: @Binary111 I edited my answer. Regex outputs a list. I assigned that list to the variable `num`. You can print `num[0]` to get the number.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ast.literal_eval` on the single element in that list (which you shouldn't call `str` because it masks the built-in, and it isn't a string anyway), within curly braces (as it seems to be a dictionary element):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = ['"Consumers_Of_Product": {"count": 13115}']
>>> ast.literal_eval('{{{}}}'.format(s[0]))
{'Consumers_Of_Product': {'count': 13115}}
```

Comment: I am still getting an error extracting this integer for some reason.

Comment: @Binary111 - I don't know what you're trying or how it's failing, so I'm afraid I can't help without more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have [3 options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949533/python-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval-vs-json-decode)

But it's recommended to use `json` lib

```
import json
s = ['"Consumers_Of_Product": {"count": 13115}']
s[0] = '{' + s[0] + '}'
my_var = json.loads(s[0]) # this is where you translate from string to dict
print my_var['Consumers_Of_Product']['count']
# 13115
```

> remembering what [TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928255/how-to-extract-number-from-text-in-python/39928276#39928276) said about why you shouldn't use `str`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regular expression` to extract anything you want from a string. Here is a link about [HOW TO use Regular expression in python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

sample code here:

```
import re
m = re.search(r'(\d+)', s[0])
if m:
    print m.group()
else:
    print 'nothing found'
```

Your string looks something like a `JSON` string, so if you are dealing with json string, you can make use of `json` package to extract the value for field `count`

sample code here (you need to wrap your string with `{}` or array `[]` ):

```
import json
obj = json.loads('{"Consumers_Of_Product": {"count": 13115}}')
print(obj['Consumers_Of_Product']['count'])
```