# Most efficient way to store this vector?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a JSON string which contains a dictionary mapping index to `float` values. This is representative of a vector. For example,

```
{
    'distro': {0: 2.42, 3: 2.56},
    'constant': 4.55
    'size': 10000
}
```

represents a vector of size `10000` having `2.42` on index `0` and `2.56` on index `2`. All other values in this vector are `4.55`.

What's the most *efficient* way to represent this data structure? Will [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) help me? My main application is to create dense representations quickly, but I don't want to store them in memory beforehand (since there are many such vectors).

Comment: what you have is already pretty space efficient (the json..) what sort of (mathmatical?) operations do you need this datatype to support?

Comment: I need to create its dense representation fast. Running a `for` loop is going too slow

Comment: once you have created this array, what do you need to do with it that requires access to it's elements? not all sparse array classes support all of numpy's ufuncs and other functions (numpy.dot being an especially notable one)

Comment: Well I need to pass it to TensorFlow, which will then take care of it

Comment: To answer in brief, scipy cannot do this naitively, but you could probably subclass it.. Knowing how TensorFlow calls your object would let you know where you need to make modifications (does it ask for an index or a memory view, etc..)

Comment: Actually I would ideally like to have a fast function in place of my `for` loop for building the dense representation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138858/discussion-between-aaron-and-martianwars).

Comment: @Aaron, thank you! While I did not use what you answered, I realized that a dictionary was an overkill in my application. I've got it down to ~3 seconds per batch, which is fast enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your iterative way is something like this:

```
In [204]: dd = {
     ...:     'distro': {0: 2.42, 3: 2.56},
     ...:     'constant': 4.55,
     ...:     'size': 10,
     ...: }
In [205]: dd
Out[205]: {'constant': 4.55, 'distro': {0: 2.42, 3: 2.56}, 'size': 10}

In [207]: x = np.zeros(dd['size'])
In [208]: x[:] = dd['constant']
In [210]: for i,v in dd['distro'].items():
     ...:     x[i] = v
In [211]: x
Out[211]: array([ 2.42,  4.55,  4.55,  2.56,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55])
```

An alternative to the `x[:]`, is `x.fill(dd['constant'])`,but don't think there's much difference in speed.

Here's a way of setting values from the dictionary without explicit iteration:

```
In [221]: ddvals = np.array(list(dd['distro'].items()),dtype='i,f')
In [222]: ddvals
Out[222]: 
array([(0,  2.42000008), (3,  2.55999994)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
In [223]: x[ddvals['f0']]=ddvals['f1']
In [224]: x
Out[224]: 
array([ 2.42000008,  4.55      ,  4.55      ,  2.55999994,  4.55      ,
        4.55      ,  4.55      ,  4.55      ,  4.55      ,  4.55      ])
```

or without the structured array:

```
In [225]: vals = np.array(list(dd['distro'].items()))
In [226]: vals
Out[226]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  2.42],
       [ 3.  ,  2.56]])
In [227]: x[vals[:,0]] = vals[:,1]
...
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
In [228]: x[vals[:,0].astype(int)] = vals[:,1]
In [229]: x
Out[229]: array([ 2.42,  4.55,  4.55,  2.56,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55,  4.55])
```

The dictionary `items()` (or `list(items())` in PY3) gives a list of tuples.  Newer `numpy` versions don't like to use floats as indices, so we have to add a few steps to preserve the integer key values.

This might be the simplest:

```
x[list(dd['distro'].keys())] = list(dd['distro'].values())
```

(I assume `keys`, `values` and `items` return values in the same key order).

For this small case I suspect the plain iterative approach is faster.  But something much larger one of that latter ones is probably better.  I can't predict where the cross over occurs.

`scipy.sparse` makes 2d matrices.  It does not implement any sort of `const` fill. (Pandas sparse does have such a fill).  We could certainly construct a `sparse` matrix from `dd['size']` and `dd['distro']`.  But I don't know if it will offer any speed advantages.

And if Tensorflow is your real target, then you may need to look more at its construction methods.  Maybe you don't need to pass through `numpy` or `sparse` at all.

---

This `x`, without the `const` can be represented as a `scipy` sparse matrix with:

```
In [247]: Xo = sparse.coo_matrix([x])
In [248]: Xo
Out[248]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Its key attributes are:

```
In [249]: Xo.data
Out[249]: array([ 2.42,  2.56])
In [250]: Xo.row
Out[250]: array([0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [251]: Xo.col
Out[251]: array([0, 3], dtype=int32)
In [252]: Xo.shape
Out[252]: (1, 10)
```

`Xr=Xo.tocsr()` the `csr` format is similar, except the `row` attribute is replaced with a `indptr` array, which has one value per row (+1), so it doesnt' grow with the number of non-zero terms.  It is used for most sparse math.

There is also a `dok` format, which is actually a dictionary subclass:

```
In [258]: dict(Xo.todok())
Out[258]: {(0, 0): 2.4199999999999999, (0, 3): 2.5600000000000001}
```

---

If the input is valid `json`, you will need to convert index keys to integer.

```
In [281]: jstr
Out[281]: '{"distro": {"0": 2.42, "3": 2.56}, "constant": 4.55, "size": 10}'
In [282]: jdd = json.loads(jstr)
In [283]: jdd
Out[283]: {'constant': 4.55, 'distro': {'0': 2.42, '3': 2.56}, 'size': 10}
In [284]: list(jdd['distro'].keys())
Out[284]: ['0', '3']
In [285]: np.array(list(jdd['distro'].keys()),int)
Out[285]: array([0, 3])
In [286]: np.array(list(jdd['distro'].values()))
Out[286]: array([ 2.42,  2.56])
```

My impression from SO searches is that `json.load` is as fast, if not faster than `eval`.  It has to parse a much simpler syntax.

[python eval vs ast.literal_eval vs JSON decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949533/python-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval-vs-json-decode)

If you can process the `json` strings, and store them in some sort intermediate data structure there are several possibilities.  How 'sparse' are these vectors?  If the dictionary has values for nearly all the 1000 'size' entries, it may be best to build the full numpy array and save that that (e.g. with `np.save/load` pair).

If it is sparse (say 10% of the values being non-const), the saving the 2 index and values arrays may make more sense (out 285 and 284).  Either keep them separate, or join them in the kind of structured array I produced earlier.

Comment: you should see the discussion on the main comments thread, OP's problem is actually speed of parsing the json not allocation of arrays....

Comment: If the input is valid `json`, then `json.loads` may be as fast as `eval`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20276991/901925.  However the `distro` keys will be strings, not integers in valid `json`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion, I have come up with an example of converting your json to an easy (fast) to parse binary format. see comments for description. I used `BytesIO` for testing, but you would likely simply use a file opened in 'rb' mode.

```
import numpy as np
import struct
import io


test_json = '''{
    'distro': {0: 2.42, 3: 2.56},
    'constant': 4.55,
    'size': 10000
}'''

#this will be slow but only have to take place once..
def json_to_bin(test_json):
    j = eval(test_json) #json provided was not well formed json, but was well formed python dict..
    const = j['constant']
    size = j['size']
    n = len(j['distro'])
    keys = j['distro'].keys()
    vals = [j['distro'][key] for key in keys]

    buf = io.BytesIO() #dummy file like object
    #struct.pack args:
        # format_string, *values_described_in_format_string
    buf.write(struct.pack("dii{0}i{0}d".format(n), const, size, n, *keys, *vals))
    return buf

def bin_to_arr(buf):
    buf.seek(0)
    #unpack our first three values 
    #most important is n so we can unpack the right number of keys and values
    const, size, n = struct.unpack("dii", buf.read(16)) #struct.calcsize('dii') = 16
    #unpack keys
    fmt = "{}i".format(n)
    nbytes = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    keys = np.array(struct.unpack(fmt, buf.read(nbytes))) #returns array (for indexing)
    #unpack vals
    fmt = "{}d".format(n)
    nbytes = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    vals = struct.unpack(fmt, buf.read(nbytes)) #returns tuple
    #create ndarray
    arr = np.empty(size)
    arr.fill(const)
    arr[keys] = vals
    return arr

print(test_json)
print('=======binary========')
buf = json_to_bin(test_json)
buf.seek(0)
print(buf.read())
arr = bin_to_arr(buf)
```