# Pandas multiprocessing apply running out of memory

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a dataframe with one of the columns as a list and another column as a dictionary. However, this is not consistent. It could be a single element or NULL too

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[1,1,1,2,3,4,4],
'shop_id':['S1','S2','S3','S2','S3','S1','S2'], 
'price_list':["{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']}",'50','NaN',"{'10':['S1','S2','S3'],'25':['S4']}","{'10':['S1','S2','S3'],'25':['S4']}"]})


+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+
| item_id | shop_id |                      price_list                  |
+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | S1      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
|       1 | S2      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
|       1 | S3      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
|       2 | S2      | 50                                               |
|       3 | S3      | NaN                                              |
|       4 | S1      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']}         |
|       4 | S2      | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']}         |
+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like this to be expanded as this:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| item_id | shop_id | price |
+---------+---------+-------+
|       1 | S1      | 10    |
|       1 | S2      | 10    |
|       1 | S3      | 20    |
|       2 | S2      | 50    |
|       3 | S3      | NaN   |
|       4 | S1      | 10    |
|       4 | S2      | 10    |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

I have tried with apply :

```
def get_price(row):
    if row['price_list'][0]=='{':
        prices = eval(row['price_list'])
        for key,value in prices.items():
            if str(row['shop_id']) in value:
                price = key
                break
            price =  np.nan
    else:
        price =  row["price_list"]
    return price


df['price'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_price(row),axis=1)
```

(The dictionary elements in the price_list column are actually strings, so I need them to be evaluated as dicts first.)

But the above approach takes a lot of time since my dataframe is pretty large.

Hence I tried using multiprocessing. My approach using multiprocessing is as below:

```
def get_price(row):
    if row['price_list'][0]=='{':
        prices = eval(row['price_list'])
        for key,value in prices.items():
            if str(row['shop_id']) in value:
                price = key
                break
            price =  np.nan
    else:
        price =  row["price_list"]
    return price

def parallelize(data, get_price, num_of_processes):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes)
    pool = mp.Pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(get_price, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def run_on_subset(get_price, data_subset):
    data_subset['price'] = data_subset.apply(get_price, axis=1)
    return data_subset

def parallelize_on_rows(data, get_price, num_of_processes):
    return parallelize(data, partial(run_on_subset, get_price), num_of_processes)

df = parallelize_on_rows(df,get_price,num_processes)
```

Now, while I used to run apply on a single core, it will go all the way through. But after using multiprocessing with all 4 cores I get out of memory error and the kernel dies.

I have 16Gb of RAM and 4 cores. When the script starts, I'm already using 8Gb. I'm running 64-bit Python 3.6.

I'm running linux and just using Pool from multiprocessing.

How can I run the script all the way through using multiprocessing without using fewer cores?

Comment: Your dataframe is being copied into each process. You can try to figure out a way to share state, but that is not trivial in multiprocessing.

Comment: as an aside, you should just considering converting this tot a list comprehension, but the fundamental problem is that your operation is super slow because of the way your data is organized. having to `eval` millions of things is not going to be performant, the fact that you are reaching for `eval` at all is a problem

Comment: And even more fundamentally, the way you've organized your data require *a linear scan*. So, you should have some data structure that is *indexed/keyed by product*, then you just query that data structure with the product. This could literally just be a giant `dict`. Just throwing more cores is probably not the first way I would handle performance here

Comment: on the topic of performance [json.loads is faster than eval for reading string dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276991/15649230)

Answer (score 0):

instead of splitting the input to `num_of_processes` consider splitting it to like 10-20 times that number, this way only 5-10% of the data gets copied to the other process at one time, also consider fixing the `chunksize` parameter of `map` as it takes a value that depends on the number of inputs by default, which may not be 1, so you risk sending more data than you intend to the other process.

```py
def parallelize(data, get_price, num_of_processes):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_of_processes*20)
    pool = mp.Pool(num_of_processes)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(get_price, data_split, chunksize=1))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data
```