# Convert a list of combination of str list to a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of string like the following, and I want to convert it to the following; could you please help me with that;

Here is my list:

`IN = ['7','8',"['#15140C', '#977E4F']"]`

And here is the output that I want.

```
OUTput = [7,8,['#15140C', '#977E4F']]
```

I try to use [float(i) for I in range(Len(list))].

Comment: Here's a hint: `['#15140C', '#977E4F']` isn't a `float`, so your `OUTput =` line will fail. Also, there's no real need to try to do this in a single line.

Comment: Yes. I can convert the first part, but for the second part, I have a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi this appears to be, instead, a list of string representations of other things.

Comment: @Karl oops, I misread the first two strings as integers and thought op only needed to convert the third string to a list. The solution for the string representation of a list will also work for the string representation of an int, so that link should still be helpful!

Comment: You can use eval on each item to build the output list : `OUTput = list(map(eval,IN))`

Comment: OP, were you helped by either of the answers provided? If so, please mark one as "accepted"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@ddejohn*'s answer relies on input to be trusted, which is not always the case **`^U`**.

As they corrected me, `ast.literal_eval()` is much safer than `eval()`, and hardly less safe than JSON parsing.  Still, [`json.loads()` turns out to be much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276991/9288580)!

So here's a JSON solution:

```
>>> import json
>>> IN = ['7','8',"['#15140C', '#977E4F']"]
>>> [json.loads(s.replace("'", '"')) for s in IN]
[7, 8, ['#15140C', '#977E4F']]
```

(Since JSON uses double quotes for strings, we have to replace single quotes before deserializing).

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` only parses Python literals, which is perfectly safe -- you're thinking about `eval()` which executes arbitrary Python.

Comment: I know the difference between `eval` and `literal_eval`, and it might be a prejudice, but I'm always thrown off by anything `eval`-like.  You are probably right, I'll amend my answer to be less dogmatic =)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate those strings as literals:

```py
In [1]: from ast import literal_eval

In [2]: IN = ['7','8',"['#15140C', '#977E4F']"]

In [3]: [literal_eval(x) for x in IN]
Out[3]: [7, 8, ['#15140C', '#977E4F']]
```